# Dreamfactory - Service user is deactivated

Tags: bitnami, dreamfactory

While meddling with an experimental Dreamfactory 2.1 installation, the user service was accidentally disabled through the admin console. The message when trying to log in is

> Service user is deactivated

How to get around this problem? Is there a configuration file or something that I need to edit to get this back on? After a bit of probing I saw this in the table called "service" in MySQL db(bitnami_dreamfactory).

```
+-------------------------+-----------+
| name                    | is_active |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| system                  |         1 |
| api_docs                |         1 |
| files                   |         0 |
| db                      |         0 |
| email                   |         0 |
| user                    |         0 |
| mysql                   |         0 |
| mongodb                 |         1 |
| scr-insert              |         1 |
| testdb                  |         1 |
| test-mlabs              |         1 |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

Can I just go ahead an issue an update statement to set 0 to 1, for 'user' service?

Thanks,
M&M

Comment: I have tried setting the is_active value to 1 but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and then clear the application cache using 'php artisan cache:clear'.